# MPMoviePlayerController - Video stops when I change contentURL

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

While a movie is playing, if I change my contentURL the movie stops playing and the view is removed.

I've tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383821/set-contenturl-of-mpmovieplayercontroller-twice/5392786#5392786) but it still doesn't work.

Here's my code to play the movie:

```
- (void) playMovie:(NSURL *)moviePath{
theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: moviePath];

UIView * movieView = [theMovie view];

[movieView setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform;
landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(landscapeTransform, 80, 80);
[movieView setTransform: landscapeTransform];

self.theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
self.theMovie.fullscreen = TRUE;
self.theMovie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[self performSelector:@selector(showCtrlsOnTouch) withObject:NULL afterDelay:0.1];
[self.theMovie prepareToPlay];

int a = currentMovie;
int b = [self.tableDataSource count] - 1;

if(a < b)
{
    UIButton *nextButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    nextButton.frame = CGRectMake(360.0, 138.0, 100.0, 44.0);
    [nextButton setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.theMovie.view addSubview:nextButton];
    [nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playNextMovie:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
if(currentMovie > 0)
{
    UIButton *previousButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    previousButton.frame = CGRectMake(40.0, 138.0, 100.0, 44.0);
    [previousButton setTitle:@"Prev" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.theMovie.view addSubview:previousButton];
    [previousButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playPreviousMovie:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview: movieView];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                             name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object: self.theMovie];}
```

And here's my code to switch the movie:

```
- (void) playNextMovie:(id) sender{
currentMovie++;

NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:currentMovie];

NSString *videoString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"videoFile"]];
NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:videoString ofType:@"m4v"];
NSLog(@"Video Path: %@", videoPath);
NSURL *moviePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: videoPath];

self.theMovie.contentURL = moviePath;
[self.theMovie prepareToPlay];}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: why do you want to change the `contentURL` while playing ?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Client wants extra controls to move between a list of videos. Always a client request!

Answer (score 0):

It is totally normal for the player to stop playing once a new `contentURL` is supplied.

The `MPMoviePlayerController.view` however is usually not being removed automatically. I am assuming that you forgot about one of your notification handlers doing something like that for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. Looking at Apple's docs it seems like all I needed to do was update the content URL:

If you set this property while a movie is playing, that movie pauses and the new movie begins loading. The new movie starts playing at the beginning.